# Translate a Go nested array of struct to C using CGO?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am trying to create a struct, in Go, where one of it's children is an array of struct and then translate it to C using CGO.

I tried something like this in Go

```
*/
typedef struct FileInfo{
    int64_t Size;
    char *Name;
}FileInfo;

typedef struct Result{
    FileInfo **files;
}Result;

int64_t GetResult(void **presult, FileInfo **files) {
    Result *result = (Result *)malloc(sizeof(Result));
    result->files=files;

    *presult = result;

    int64_t ptr = (int64_t)result;

    return ptr;
}
*/
import "C"
```

```
func Run() {
    var arr []*C.struct_FileInfo

    ai := C.struct_FileInfo{
        Size: C.int64_t(1234),
        Name: C.CString("some name"),
    }

    arr = append(arr, &ai)

    var presult unsafe.Pointer
    ptr := C.GetResult(&presult, &arr[0])

    println("\nResult struct pointer: %v", ptr)
}
```

It threw an `panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer` error.

How to I fix this error?

### Updates:

Working playground url: https://play.golang.org/p/vpLddEyY8kI

Comment: Your `ai` value is allocated in Go. You have to allocate C memory using cgo exactly like you would in C.

Comment: @JimB I tried everything possible, I'd appreciate if you could share a code snippet. Regards.

Comment: @GaneshRathinavel, use `C.malloc` to allocate the memory for `C.struct_FileInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

- `arr` is a slice of pointers (`*C.struct_FileInfo`).
- `&arr[0]` takes the address of (a pointer to) the first element of that slice.
- The `ai` variable, the address of which becomes the first element of `arr`, is allocated by Go.

Hence:

- `arr[0]` contains `&ai`, which is a pointer to `C.struct_FileInfo` allocated by Go.
- `arr` is also managed by Go and hence `&arr[0]` is "a Go pointer to Go pointer".

Please read [this](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers) thoroughly.

### Possible solution

One solution is to call `C.malloc` to allocate enough bytes to store a `C.struct_FileInfo`. This way, you will have Go pointer (&arr[0]) to C pointer, which is fine.

Don't forget to `C.free` it after you're done with that memory.

Comment: Thanks it worked. https://play.golang.org/p/vpLddEyY8kI